# Sending events between two Meteor servers

Tags: websocket, meteor, socket.io

Is there a way to send events between two Meteor servers? I know I can connect Server1 to Server2 (and vice versa) using DDP.connect and just call methods between the two servers. This will not work for me, because one of my servers (Server1) will be at my house behind a dynamic IP and firewall. DDP.connect requires a url. What is the best way, if any, to communicate between the two servers? I am thinking the only way to do this would be something like Socket.io where Server1 connects to Server2. I'm not sure if this can be done in Meteor though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using DDP.connect to connect server 1 to server 2 on startup, then subscribing to a collection that server 2 publishes, for example:

On Server 2 (known URL):

```
var Events = new Meteor.Collection("events");

Meteor.publish("events", function () {
  return Events.find({});
}
```

On Server 1 (at your house):

```
var EventConnection = DDP.connect("<server 2 URL>");
var Events = new Meteor.Collection("events", {connection: EventConnection});

EventConnection.subscribe("events");

Events.find({}).observe({
  added: function (newEvent) {
    // do something with newEvent
  }
});
```

Then, whenever server 2 adds an object to the Events collection, you will get it on server 1 via the connection. Watch out, though - every time server 1 connects to server 2 it will get all previous events as well. If you don't want that to happen, you need to use the ready callback on subscribe:

Revised code for Server 1:

```
var EventConnection = DDP.connect("<server 2 URL>");
var Events = new Meteor.Collection("events", {connection: EventConnection});

EventConnection.subscribe("events", function () {
  Events.find({}).observe({
    added: function (newEvent) {
      // do something with newEvent
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for the help. I still hate that I have to interact with the database to send events, but maybe this will change in the future.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `publish`, you'll see that the second code example shows you how to use `publish` without a database. http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish This is a little more complicated, though, so using the database would be the easier way to go.

Comment: I have a similar case, but server2(known url) is the one where you subscribe to the server1(dynamic ip). Hence the connection should happen in a reverse way. Is that possible ?

Comment: Interesting, that's not currently supported I think. You would first need to get the IP of the other server and connect in the right direction. You could do this by sending a request first, before opening the DDP connection.